# iPhone, iTouch, iPad Bluetooth Connection to Generic Bluetooth Device

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, bluetooth, ipod

Trying to get iPhone / iPad / iPod Touch to connect to a generic Bluetooth Device.

Works for Windows 7 Bluetooth / Android Bluetooth / Mac Laptop Bluetooth, but does not seem to work with any of the Apple iOS devices.

I assume that this is an Apple decision to limit the user of Bluetooth Devices to only the devices that they seem "correct".  So just want to make sure this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the generic bluetooth device ? and what bluetooth profile does it use ?
Devices connect only with compatible devices which have the compatible profile, not all devices support all profiles. 
In Addition with iOS if you are using SPP there is additional requirement to develop as per the Apple MFi guidelines.

Comment: It's a generic Bluetooth Modem that works an all other platforms...  Just learned that for BlueTooth device you have to be part of the hardware program and use the encoder chip, the same one that is used to turn on video for cable out.  I will answer this tomorrow when I can, thanks

Comment: Has anyone come across some Obj-C code samples illustrating the use of BLE?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Bluetooth 4.0 Low Energy device, you can do it using the new Core Bluetooth framework (assuming you have an iPhone 4S). Otherwise, as noted, only approved devices will connect.